# Inserir no Banco um dado vindo de um Combobox (PHP)

Tags: php, html, combobox, crud, inserir

Olá, estou montando um sistema para o projeto de faculdade. Tenho um relacionamento entre Cidade----Estado. Pois bem, o CRUD de estado já esta funcionando e armazenando no Database, quando eu vou cadastrar uma cidade, essa cidade precisa de um estado cadastrado, então, os campos de cadastrar a cidade ficaram.

"Nome da cidade"(input tipo texto) e UF(Combobox já povoada através de um select)
Quando eu tento armazenar no banco o nome da cidade e o estado vindo de um combobox não aparece nada no banco, mesmo não apontando nenhum erro. Como eu realizo o insert no db usando um estado no combobox

```
<?php
include 'inc/funcoes.php';
$banco = abrirBanco();
?>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Cadastro de Cidade</title>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    </head>
    <body>
        <form name="Cidade" action="inc/funcoes.php" method="POST">
            Nome da Cidade:
            <input type="text" name="cidade" size="30" />
            UF:
            <select name="estados">
                <option value="">Selecione</option>
                <?php
                $sql = "SELECT * FROM estado";
                $resultado = $banco->query($sql);
                while($row_estados = $resultado->fetch_array()){ 
                ?>
                <option value="<?=$row_estados['idestado']?>"><?=$row_estados['nomeestado']?></option>
                <?php
                }
                ?>
            </select><br><br>
            <input type="hidden" name="acao" value="inserirCidade"/>
            <input type="submit" value="Cadastrar Cidade">
            <input type="reset" value="Limpar Dados">
        </form>
    </body>
</html>
```

Função do povoamento do combobox Linha:17 - 26

Comment: Neste código que você mostrou, você não está inserindo nada no banco de dados.

Comment: A tabela `cidade` possui a coluna para a chave estrangeira de `estado`?

Comment: estava gravando com o nome errado na tabela, mas pra simplificar eu resolvi fazer como o amigo abaixo falou, usando uma função em javascript para buscar os dados da combobox

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Se percebi bem a sua pergunta depois de popular a ComboBox (CB), a minha sugestão seria através de JavaScript (ou jQuery), ir buscar o valor que está na CB e enviar para um PHP onde fará a *query* SQL para adicionar esse valor à sua Base de Dados.

JQuery(JS):

```
$(input[type='submit']).on("click", function(){
       var campoCB = $(select[name='estados']).val();
    $.ajax({
        url: 'script.php',
        type: 'POST' //ou GET
        data: {campo: campoCB},
        dataType: 'json' //por exemplo, pode ser, csv, text, etc...
        success: function(data){
            //código a executar depois de enviar o parametro para o servidor
        }
    })
}
```

no PHP recebe o campo e escreve a query SQL aqui com o parametro que passou do JS

PHP:

```
$campo = $_POST['campo'];
```

*====EDIÇÃO====*

Se não precisar de uma chamada assíncrona (AJAX), pode enviar o argumento por exemplo, por *POST/GET* através do `form`, quando dá a submissão. Envia e recebe o argumento no PHP como mostrei acima.

Comment: Por quê enviar por uma requisição assíncrona e não só pela submissão normal do formulário em uma requisição síncrona?

Comment: Tem razão, é verdade. Não é necessário. Deixei-me levar por um trabalho  que estou a fazer agora, por isso usei o ajax. Já editei a resposta. Obrigado!

Comment: Valeu, deu certo, consegui gravar no banco, outra pequena duvida... Eu tenho o cadastro de pessoa que depende dessa cidade e estado, tem como eu selecionar o Estado, e depois, só retornar pra mim, as cidades que estão vinculadas com o id desse estado, eu tentei usando o script da google jsapi. mas ele não retorna nenhuma cidade, vou postar os codigos

Comment: Função usando o Google JSAPI: https://pastebin.com/w24f9dBA
Select das cidades inc/subcategoria cidade.php: https://pastebin.com/tHfeKSFN

Comment: Poderá fazer essa associação através de SQL utilizando um JOIN, se na tabela da pessoa tiver referencia da chave estrangeira da tabela da cidade e estado.

Se não percebeu, pode postar o esquema relacional das tabelas, pf?

Comment: postei uma foto com o modelo relacional

Comment: Pelo que percebi, o que quer é uma query SQL que devolva as cidades pertencentes a um estado, certo? Se entendi bem, a query é a seguinte:

`SELECT nomecidade FROM cidade c JOIN estado e ON c.estado_idestado = e.idestado`

Comment: Deu certo ate certo ponto fraza0, na verdade, ele esta buscando todas as cidade, o que eu preciso é: Primeiro seleciono o estado em uma combobox, e logo após isso em outra combobox me retorna somente cidades que tem a chave estrangeira daquele estado.

Answer (score 0):

[image]

Aqui esta a parte das relações entre Estado--Cidade---Endereço---Pessoa.